# Erlang gen_tcp:recv http_request abs_path

Tags: erlang, gen-tcp

I'm writing code in Erlang that accepts HTTP requests. I have working code which is shown below.

The problem I have is that I'm unsure about the returned result of `gen_tcp:recv`.

I create a listening socket and accept sockets using

```
{ok, ListenSock}=gen_tcp:listen(Port, [list,{active, false},{packet,http}])
{ok, Sock}=gen_tcp:accept(ListenSock),
```

I accept a GET request (or any other) using

```
{ok, {http_request, Method, Path, Version}} = gen_tcp:recv(Sock, 0),
handle_get(Sock, Path);
```

Then, to get url parameters (CGI parameters, e.g., `?foo=1&bar=2`) I have to match `Path` with a structure `{abs_path, RelativePath}`.

```
handle_get(Sock, ReqPath) ->
    {abs_path, RelPath} = ReqPath,
    Parameters = string:substr(RelPath, string:str(RelPath, "?") + 1),
```

While I was reading through the docs of Erlang about `gen_tcp` and more specifically the `recv` method I found [the page describing `HttpPacket`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#decode_packet-3).

The grammar on the page clearly shows that `Path` in `HttpPacket`, and in this case the `HttpRequest` type, can have multiple types of `HttpUri`.

```
HttpRequest = {http_request, HttpMethod, HttpUri, HttpVersion}
HttpUri = '*'
        | {absoluteURI,
           http | https,
           Host :: HttpString,
           Port :: inet:port_number() | undefined,
           Path :: HttpString}
        | {scheme, Scheme :: HttpString, HttpString}
        | {abs_path, HttpString}
        | HttpString
```

I understand that I have to support each of these possible cases, however I am not sure. I am also wondering how I can test these cases. I have tried using `curl` and `RESTClient` in Firefox and both of them make `gen_tcp:recv` return `abs_path`.

So to be clear, how is determined whether the request holds `{abs_path, HttpString}`, `{scheme, Scheme :: HttpString, HttpString}` or `{absoluteURI,...}` and do I need to support all of them?

## Full listing

```
start(Port)->
    {ok, ListenSock}=gen_tcp:listen(Port, [list,{active, false},{packet,http}]),
    loop(ListenSock).


loop(ListenSock) -> 
    {ok, Sock}=gen_tcp:accept(ListenSock),
    spawn(?MODULE, handle_request, [Sock]),
    loop(ListenSock).

%% Takes a TCP socket and receives 
%% http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#decode_packet-3
handle_request(Sock) ->
    {ok, {http_request, Method, Path, _Version}} = gen_tcp:recv(Sock, 0),

    case (Method) of
        'GET' ->
            handle_get(Sock, Path);
        _ -> 
            send_unsupported_error(Sock)
    end.

handle_get(Sock, ReqPath) ->
    {abs_path, RelPath} = ReqPath,
    Parameters = string:substr(RelPath, string:str(RelPath, "?") + 1),
    %% Debugging
    ParsedParms = httpd:parse_query(Parameters),
    io:fwrite("Full Path: ~p~nParameters: ~p~n", [RelPath, ParsedParms]),
    %% End Debugging
    send_accept(Sock).
```

Comment: Why are you writing your own web server? It's more work than you think.

Comment: I'm not writing my own web server. All my code needs to do is accept get requests with parameters in the url. I do not intend do handle anthing else.

Comment: What about HTTP headers accompanying a GET request?

Comment: The relevant headers are handled. I have not listed that code as that was not relevant for my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple network-capable client such as netcat (`/usr/bin/nc` on my system) to send whatever form of request you like. For example, the following connects to a web server listening on `localhost` port 8000 and sends a `GET` request where the path is a URL (note that the `$` denotes a shell prompt):

```
$ nc localhost 8000
GET http://stackoverflow.com HTTP/1.1

$
```

The `nc` program reads from its standard input. Be sure to hit enter twice after the `GET` line to properly indicate the end of the HTTP headers. This results in the `gen_tcp:recv` call on the server returning:

```
{absoluteURI,http,"stackoverflow.com",undefined,"/"}
```

Similarly, the following will return a path from `gen_tcp:recv` that's not an `{abs_path, ...}` tuple, but rather just `"../foo"`:

```
$ nc localhost 8000
GET ../foo HTTP/1.1

$
```

You can easily set up test variations like these in text files and feed them into `nc` using stdin redirection.

Comment: Aha, this answers everything I wanted to know! Thank you!